# CSS for wordpress theme only rendering correctly in Chrome

Tags: css

I have used a wordpress theme from WPShower called Sight 1.0 on www.agoracollective.org . It works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox and Internet Explorer the CSS file does not render. Tested on multiple machines and OS. Have not had any luck searching for resolution on google. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have MULTIPLE errors in the css files. In Firefox, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to pop up the error console, and you'll see them flood by. Most of your CSS file is being ignored due to the parseing errors

e.g. /wp-content/plugins/events-manager/includes/css/events_manager.css, line 61:

```
}    <--dangling {, no matching } above
/* Add Event Form */
```

/wp-content/themes/sight-1/style.css, line 25:

```
body {font: 62.5% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"; background: #27292a url("http://www.agoracollective.org/ablog/images/backg.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat; 
                                              ^---dangling "
```

and so on and so on and so on.